# including multiple gitignore files in one

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is the content of a gitignore of YADR, a popular project built on top of zsh :

```
  1 # OSX       taken from: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/OSX.gitignore
  2 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3 .DS_Store
  4 # Thumbnails
  5 ._*
  6 # Files that might appear on external disk
  7 .Spotlight-V100
  8 .Trashes
  9
 10 # Windows   taken from: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Windows.gitignore
 11 # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 12 # Windows image file caches
 13 Thumbs.db
 ...
```

That looks like an awful solution.

=> 
Is it not possible to include multiple gitignore, and have them maintained separately ?

Comment: Only thing awful about it is making such a big deal about where they got such ubiquitous entries.

Comment: Why is this an awful solution? If the project can be run/used on multiple platforms, you have to exclude the _garbage_ files from the OS. Projects running just on Windows might be fine with using just the Windows ignore definitions, etc.

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with 'ubiquitous entries'. it is about composition. obviously. if one size fit all was a good answer, we'd 'preinstall' everything on a computer... unless you missed the last 20 years of tech, it is all about componentization and modularity, cf github and co

Answer (score 3):

There is no include in a `.gitignore` for now (Git 2.18, 2018), as (not) seen in the [gitignore man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

The composition is done through multiple `.gitignore` files at multiple folder levels (one `.gitignore` per folder): the `.gitignore` in the deepest folder adds its rules to the ones from `.gitignore` of direct parent folders.